# DocuSign API integration in Node.js and handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, docusignapi

I am making a node application with handlebars. 
The website contains normal signup and login functionality. After that, User has to fill a Form which contains his/her basic information. There he/she has to do a digital signature on it. 
I want to do this by DocuSign.
I want that each time any new user signup, then he/she can do sign on the form.

I see the DocuSign docs but I am not clear about how to do dynamically with different users. I am able to do the sign manually by creating an account on DocuSign website. Then write the integration key on code and creating a template of form. 
But I am unable to do all these by the code in nodejs.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want:

1. Someone visits your web app
2. They use forms to add data to your web app
3. Your web app will create a document based on the data entered.
4. The visitor will then sign the document using DocuSign.

Very do-able:

1. Your web app can create the document to be signed in multiple ways. Your app can create a PDF, or many other document types. I suggest that you start with an HTML document. Note that an HTML doc can't include external content such as links to a css file or graphics. See example 2 of [eg-03-node-auth-code grant](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant) for an example of this technique.

   An alternative is to use a PDF of a form as a DocuSign template. Then your envelope will fill in values for the template. See example 16 of [eg-03-node-auth-code grant](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant)
2. Next, your web app needs to create an envelope in DocuSign and present it for embedded signing to the web app visitor. First, get a DocuSign access token by using the JWT Grant flow. Use this flow since the signer doesn't have their own account on DocuSign. If the envelopes are "from" the HR department then use a generic HR department user id.  Example of using JWT Grant in Node.JS: [eg-01-node-jwt](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-node-jwt)
3. Use the access token to create the envelope and then open an embedded signing ceremony for your web app visitor. See example 1 of [eg-03-node-auth-code grant](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant) for this part.

Comment: Yes you are corrrect. I want the same.

Comment: I have apply these examples but here is one thing that I dont want. Whenever I click on any link, then it redirects me to open with docusign account. I dont want any redirection. I want that user sign on the page on my website.
Second thing is that there can be many user who can access the website. So is it neccessary to have account of all users on Docusign.

Comment: I am new to node, and this docusign is very hard for me to implement. Thank @Larry-K for the response and sorry for english. I am stuck with Docusign from last one week.
I hope it will solved soon with help of you such guys on stackoverflow

Comment: Hey @LokeshSaini, Have you got the answer for this ?